# How to pass computed values to a constructor in ES6 classes through static or prototype methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Hello I have the following code:

```
export default class UserData {
  constructor(days = {}, firstDay = getFirstDay(), lastAccessDay){
    this.days = days;
    this.firstDay = firstDay || getFirstDay();
    this.lastAccessDay = lastAccessDay;
  }

  static getFirstDay() {
    return new Date();
  }
}
```

The idea was that if I don't pass a value to the constructor it would use a static method to calculate the firstDay.

The problem is that to the constructor getFirstDay() is undefined.

I'm a bit confused about what would the best way to set this up following best practices and conventions.

Comment: Yes, the variable `getFirstDay` is undefined. It's a static method.

Comment: You should call it either as the default parameter value *or* behind the `||` operator, not in both places.

Comment: So how would I fix this and pass to the constructor a computed value with a method inside the class? @Bergi

Comment: getFirstDay is undefined, but UserData.getFirstDay **is not** and can be used in the constructor as a default param. it's a little different than i've seen in standard practice, but it's still possible.

Comment: @EnricoPolanski Use the class to access the method: `constructor(days = {}, firstDay = UserData.getFirstDay(), lastAccessDay) { … }`. See the duplicate for details.

Comment: @Bergi dude, that's the answer i was going to post.

Comment: not a duplicate.